# Validate both JS Date and Firestore Date with Joi

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I'm currently discovering `Joi` library and - at this time - it's a great experience.
However, I'm facing a tiny problem I can't resolve. Help or advice needed!

Consider the following schema (a bit):

```
const workSchema = Joi.object({ timeline_created: Joi.date().allow(null).required()) }
```

It works perfectly fine when I submit a `JS` date (or `null` value).
However, I'm using `Firestore` which convert JS Date to this kind of object:

```
timeline_created: Timestamp { _seconds: 1637258607, _nanoseconds: 349000000 }
```

Thus, I can't validate my schema (it's not a date `Joi` knows).
Then, my question: how to write my schema (I want it to be strict/precise) but validating at the same time a `JS Date` and a `Firestore Date`.

Thanks

EDIT: I made some progress with:

```
timeline_created: Joi.object().keys({_seconds: Joi.number(),_nanoseconds: Joi.number()}).required()
```

It validates my `Firestore` object.
However, how could I also validate if `timeline_created` is `null` or a JS Date? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working:

```
Joi.alternatives([Joi.object().keys({ _seconds: Joi.number(), _nanoseconds: Joi.number() }), Joi.date(), null]).required()
```